# How to search for hashtag in a twitter embed list with Javascript

Tags: javascript, meteor, twitter-widget

I'm trying to do add a Twitter list in my Meteor application that show all tweets about a certain hashtag (the city of the visitor). I did a new widget with a general hashtag (#suisse) then I want to change this hashtag with Javascript to match it with the user's city... the problem is that I try to change the href in my JS but nothing happend it still search for #suisse. Could you help me ?

```
    <a class="twitter-timeline"  href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/suisse" data-widget-id="807191698661056513"></a>
```

And in the JS where I want to change the search

```
  document.getElementsByClassName('twitter-timeline')[0].href = "https://twitter.com/hashtag/" + Session.get('city');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if someone is in the same situation as me the response is: you can't change dynamically the #. It's writtent in the widget code and you can't change it so you need to create 1 widget per #...

Answer (score 0):

The function [document.getElementsByClassName](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp) returns a collection, not a single element. There can possibly many such elements, so you have to specify an index if you want to change some attributes. If you have only one element with this class, you can just do this:

```html
document.getElementsByClassName('twitter-timeline')[0].href = "https://twitter.com/hashtag/" + Session.get('city');
```

Comment: Oh thank you Jakob but it doesn't change the final result, the list still searching for the #suisse...